# Being good friends with a female classmate?

Tags: sharia

I am a graduate school student at a college and am living in a dorm. Over the last year, I've become good friends with a lady in my program. We have not done anything romantic nor do I plan to. However we do talk a lot and have often been alone. Am I wrong and can we keep being friends?

Comment: Although the question is not duplicate. the answer to the question is given in the one which it is marked duplicate for.

Comment: @DavidWallace that is true what you say. However the answer given in the question which it is marked for is a general answer and is applicable on all cases as this one. I am just saying that the answer is already there. Not against removing as duplicate because this question is not.